# identify npm packages no longer maintained

Tags: node.js, npm

While using `npm` packages, no matter how popular and active they were when I added them (two years ago), many of them are retired or not being maintained now. I notice it only when some **functionality is broken**.

Is there any tool to check the **health of every package I use**? So that I can use them in my build process as a gulp/grunt task to get a warning if the latest version of any package was added more than a year ago.

Comment: I'm looking for this. Did you find anything?

Answer (score 0):

It's not exactly what you're looking for but if the package isn't maintained anymore, it will have a bad score :

http://packagequality.com

Comment: thanks @krampstudio. Although this is not exactly what I am looking for, this is a good guide to code it myself.